# Can I get a pointer to a struct as a parameter from a function in C?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have a type defined like this:

```
struct DynTab_s {
    int     object_count;
    //other fields
    void    *data;
};

typedef struct DynTab_s *Dyntab_t; //note that type I use is pointer to struct
```

I have a storage utility that I can user to store and retrieve them. I've chosen to support int, double and pointer type. I have a function to retrieve the int and double values by key:

```
int MyHashtableGet(MyHashtable_t Hashtable, void *Key, void *Value)
{   
    void    *Row = NULL;
    int     RetValue = -1;

    MakeRow(Hashtable, Key, NULL, &Row);
    if (!MyStoreSelect(Hashtable->TableId, Row))
    {
        switch (Hashtable->ValueType)
        {
        case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_INT: 
            *(int *)Value = *(int *)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);
            break;
        case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_POINTER:
            //after row below I can see the DynTab_t in the item when I cast it
            Value = *(void **)*(int **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);
        break;
        }
    }
    MyFree(Row);

    return RetValue;
}
```

that work for int. But not for pointer when I try to get Dyntab_t. This works if I use function

```
void *MyHashtableGetPointer(MyHashtable_t Hashtable, void *Key)
{
    void        *Row = NULL;
    void        *RetValue = NULL;

    MakeRow(Hashtable, Key, NULL, &Row);
    if (!MyStoreSelect(Hashtable->TableId, Row))
        RetValue = *(void **)*(int **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);

    MyFree(Row);

    return RetValue;
}
```

when I call it with:

```
int       Key = 1;
DynTab_t  MyTab;

MyTab = (DynTab_t)MyHashtableGetPointer(MyHashtable, &Key);
```

The question is can I at all use this MyHashtableGet to get DynTab_t item or does second parameter have to be void ** type? If yes, can you please provide the exact syntax to call and to MyHashtableGet in case of MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_POINTER.

Thanks & BR -Matti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is can I at all use this MyHashtableGet to get DynTab_t item or does second parameter have to be void ** type?

The only difference (if you're storing the pointers like you store the `int` values) would be that when retrieving an `int`, you'd pass the address of an `int` variable; and when retrieving a pointer, you'd pass the address of a pointer variable.  A `void *` can hold the address of anything (except functions sometimes) -- including other pointers.  So the last parameter is fine as `void *`, as long as you handle it appropriately elsewhere.

I'm not sure what you're doing in your function, though.  If you store the pointers the same way as the `int`s in your data structure, so that at the same level of indirection you'd have an `int` for the integer type and a `void *` for the pointer type, then why are they dereferenced to different levels?

```
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_INT: 
        *(int *)Value = *(int *)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);
        break;
```

In the above, it seems that `((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize)` gets you the pointer to whatever value you've stored, though of the wrong pointer type.  Then the `(int *)` casts to a pointer of your data's type (`int` in this case), which you then dereference and assign to what `Value` points to.

```
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_POINTER:
        Value = *(void **)*(int **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);
    break;
```

But here, you cast to `int **`, dereference, cast to `void **`, then dereference again, and assign to `Value` instead of what `Value` points at?  Isn't that one too many dereferences?  Shouldn't you assign to the target of `Value` rather than `Value`?  And why do you need to cast to `int **` at all?  I think it should be more like this:

```
    case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_POINTER:
        *(void **)Value = *(void **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);
        break;
```

Then, when calling to get an int:

```
...
int       Val;
MyHashtableGet(Table, Key, &Val);
```

...and when calling to get a pointer:

```
...
void      *Val;
MyHashtableGet(Table, Key, &Val);
```

**Edit:**
This assumes one of two things, though: That the the variable you passed the address of in `Value` is `void *`, or that the variable you passed the address of is of a type that is internally represented the same way as `void *` (often true, but not guaranteed).  If you want to rely on the pointer type being converted on assignment (in case their representations differ), you could implement your `MyHashtableGetPointer()` function as a wrapper for `MyHashtableGet()`:

```
void *MyHashtableGetPointer(MyHashtable_t Hashtable, void *Key)
{
  void *res = NULL;
  MyHashtableGet(Hashtable, Key, &res);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks dimitri! i gotta put some thinking to your answer. hate to admit but i'm terribly with these pointers when it's get beyond the very basics. i test it tomorrow. thanks again.

Comment: If you know the pointers will always be `Dyntab_t` (`struct DynTab_s *`) then you could change `*(void **)Value = ` to `*(Dyntab_t *)Value = `, which would also take care of the difference between the internal representations of `void *` and `struct DynTab_s *` (if there is a one).

Comment: no, I don't know the type. I'm more C# programmer and I just get fed up with not having Hashtable/HashList.So I try to make it as general as possible. Anyway I start to test ur solution now!

Comment: thanks a lot dimitri! in function MyHashtableGet as you said case MY_HASHTABLE_TYPE_POINTER: *(void **)Value = *(void **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize); and in calling function calling it with parameter void *Value and then I have to cast it Tab2 = *(Dyntab_t *)Value;

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want to do it. You can do it using a reference (only in C++) or a pointer (C and C++):

```
void changeTheParamRef(struct myStruct &s)
{
    myStruct other;
    s = other; // or
    s.something = other.something;
}

void changeTheParamPtr(struct myStruct *s)
{
    myStruct other;
    *s = other; // or
    s->something = other.something;
}

void allocStruct(struct myStruct **s)
{
    *s = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
}
```

You don't need a pointer to a pointer unless you'd like to return or change a pointer instead of a value.

To call above samples:

```
myStruct s;
changeTheParamRef(s);
changeTheParamPtr(&s);

myStruct *p;
allocStruct(&p);
changeTheParamRef(*p);
changeTheParamPtr(p);
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not an answer to my question. what I want is to use 1 function, namely MyHashtableGet, to get all the values from MyHashtable. this is why I use void *Value. also getting the value from a row is a bit more complicated than in ur answer: *(void **)*(int **)((char *)Row + Hashtable->KeySize);